# How do I make TFS 2012 build separate output binaries by project framework

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Currently my TFS build outputs all the binaries to the same directory.
If TFS output the binaries from the silverlight projects to one directory and the .net framework projects to another then I would be able to differentiate between them when testing.
Anyone have any idea how I could do that?

Here is an example of what I would like to do http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/customize-binaries-folder-in-tfs-team-build/ except in that example they use configuration and project name instead of project framework.

I do not want to make any alteration whatsoever to any source code, I want to keep my changes to the build definition.

Comment: That solution involves editing project files

Comment: Ideally there should be some way of telling MSbuild that it should set the output directory based on a string and a variable in the csproj file